# Raw Socket Select Event Not occuring

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have sent message from client side and it sent successfully using sendto. But on server side I have created multiple raw sockets, to monitor event on them, used select. But event on rfds not getting noticed by select. Why so? It remains blocked on select system call.

```
   void main()
    {
        int readSet[2],i;
        struct sockaddr_in source;
        socklen_t client_addr_size;

        //Creating Socket
        readSet[0]=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,221);
        readSet[1]=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,222);


        fd_set rfds;
        struct timeval tv;


        if(readSet[0]==-1 || readSet[1]==-1)
        {
            perror("\nSocket:");
            exit(0);
        }

        printf("\nSocket Created\n");

        memset(&source, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        source.sin_family=AF_INET;
        source.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

         FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        while(1)
        {

            for(i=0; i<2; i++)
                FD_SET(readSet[i],&rfds);

            printf("\nBefore select\n");
            int ret = select(readSet[1]+1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);

            printf("\nRetval:%d\n",ret);
            if(ret>0)
            {
                for(i=0; i<2; i++)
                {
                    if(FD_ISSET(readSet[i],&rfds))
                    {
                        char buff[4096];
                        int ds=0;
                        if( (ds=recvfrom(readSet[i], buff, 4096, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&source, &client_addr_size)) <0 )
                            perror("Error in recv: \n");

                        printf("\nData Receved successfully...%d\n",ds);

                        printIPHeader((unsigned char *)buff);
                        break;
                    }

                }//For loop
            }
        }

        sleep(1);
    }


 //Client siode code
void main()
{
    int rsfd1=0,rsfd2;

    struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;
    socklen_t client_addr_size;

    //Creating Socket 
    rsfd1=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,221);
    rsfd2=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,221);

    if(rsfd1==-1 || rsfd2==-1)
    {
        perror("\nSocket:");
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("\nSocket Created: \n"); 

    const int val = 1;
    if(setsockopt(rsfd1, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &val, sizeof(val)) < 0)
    {
        perror("\nsetsockopt() error:");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(setsockopt(rsfd2, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &val, sizeof(val)) < 0)
    {
        perror("\nsetsockopt() error:");
        exit(-1);
    }

   //Constructing IP Header
    char buffer[4096];
    memset(&buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    char *msg="Hey there, how are you";
    // Our own headers' structures
    struct iphdr *iph= (struct iphdr *) buffer;

    iph->version=4;
    iph->ihl=5;
    iph->tos=16;
    iph->tot_len=htons(sizeof(iph)+sizeof(msg));
    iph->id=0;
    iph->ttl=255;    //Number of hops
    iph->protocol=253;
    iph->saddr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    iph->daddr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    int iphdrlen =iph->ihl*4;
    strcat(buffer+iphdrlen,msg);
    //End

    memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    dest_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");


    printf("\nCustom IP Header to sent...\n");
    printIPHeader((unsigned char *)buffer);
    int n=0;

    if( (n=sendto(rsfd1,buffer,23,0,(struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr,sizeof(dest_addr))) <0 )
        perror("Sendto error: ");


    char * msg1="I am fine\0";

    strcat(buffer+iphdrlen,msg1);

    //if( (n=sendto(rsfd2,buffer,23,0,(struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr,sizeof(dest_addr))) <0 )
        //perror("Sendto error: ");


    printf("\nData Sent Succefully:%d\n",n);

}
```

Comment: you should post your client code specifically the sendto logic also add
1. bind the sockets on the servers to the addresses you are sending from the client
2. have timeout in select or else it will block forever

Comment: Is there need to write bind, if we are using sendto and recvfrom? Off course if timeout mentioned it will pass the select statement but this is not what i required.

Comment: You need to bind to the address you are sending to using sendto or maybe you can atleast bind to the interface where you are expecting your packet

Comment: I've a similar problem and like to know whether you could resolve your problem and if yes how. There's a listening socket on server-side which may produce stream sockets by accept. when something is sent via this connection to the server, nothing else will be received from raw socket!